# How to retrieve visible data from Datagrid WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, filter

I have a Datagrid in my WPF application and I designed a data filter for it as well. Datagrid is automatically filled depending on the excel file user imports to application. Now, my question is how to retrieve the visible data (filtered data in datagrid) from datagrid after filter is applied?

Comment: Why not work with the source? If you apply the same filter to the source you will have the data

Comment: The problem is I have multiple functionality on my app such as adding column, deleting columns/rows etc. and I need to get the data directly from the datagrid. I guess this is the easiest way, because I don't want to store data in memory and exhaust it

Comment: "I don't want to store data in memory and exhaust it" - ???. Where do you think the data you're viewing on screen is stored at?. I don't understand your question. You developed certain functionality to filter data and now you're asking here how to get that data back? sounds senseless to me.

Comment: Ok, let me explain it better. datagrid1.ItemsSource=source, then I apply custom filter on top of this datagrid1.Itemssource=source.Filter, now I want to know what is the command to get the ItemsSource back to the code? because when I use DataTable D=datagrid1.Itemssource it doesnot work

Comment: @Amir I don't understand a word you're saying. Post your code. `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property (actually `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`) is a property of type `object`, not `DataTable`, you need to cast that if you expect C# to compile.